# Eloquent loop through array and add to DB - Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm just starting to get to grips with `eloquent` wand I'm sending the below object to my back end via `angularJS`

```
item:
     {
        id: 1, 
        cookie_id: "c312b3faf70d3bc39b9563b340a1094bf6f58891", 
        user_id: null, 
        restaurant_id: 11, 
        restaurant_name: "Gaucho",
        restaurant_uname: "gaucho",
        city: "abuja",
        location: "asokoro",
        time: "12:45:00",
        updated_at: "2016-02-05 11:37:05",
        created_at: "2016-02-05 10:50:48",
        cart_items: [
          "id": 159,
          "name": "Empanadas (Choice of 2)",
          "description": "Choice of Diced Beef; Spinach, Stilton and Onion; or Smoked Ham and Mozzarella",
          "price": 700,
          "available": 1,
          "created_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
          "updated_at": "2016-01-31 16:50:31",
          "menu_category_id": 41,
          "restaurant_id": 11,
          "cart_modifier_items": [
              {
                  "id": 34,
                  "name": "Diced Beef",
                  "price": 0,
                  "created_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:08",
                  "updated_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:08",
                  "menu_modifier_group_id": 9,
                  "restaurant_id": 11,
                  "menu_item_id": 159,
                  "selected": true
              },
              {
                  "id": 35,
                  "name": "Smoked Salmon & Mozzarella",
                  "price": 0,
                  "created_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:37",
                  "updated_at": "2016-02-01 01:04:37",
                  "menu_modifier_group_id": 9,
                  "restaurant_id": 11,
                  "menu_item_id": 159,
                  "selected": true
              }
            ]
        ]
    }
```

As you can see I have a `parent` item that contains multiple `cart_items` that then contain multiple `cart_modifier_items`

My model details (3 tables);

```
Cart 
hasMany cart_items

CartItem 

belongsTo Cart
hasMany cart_modifier_items

CartModifierItem

belongsTo CartItem
```

How can i accept this item add and loop through `cart_items` and `cart_modifier_items` and add them to me tables using `eloquent`?

`cart` to the `cart Table`
all `cart_items` to the `cart_items Table`
all `cart_modifier_items` to the `cart_modifier_items Table`

I guess I would need 3 seperate `DB` requests?

Any advice/guidance appreciated

This is what I've done so far;

```
public function addItem (Request $request) {

    $item = $request->input('item');
    $rest_id = $request->input('id');
    $cookie_id = $request->input('basket');

    $cart = Cart::where(['cookie_id' => $cookie_id, 'restaurant_id' => $rest_id])->get();
    $cart_id = $cart->id;

    $cart_items = $item['cart_items'];
    foreach($cart_items as $cart_item) {

        CartItem::create([
            'item_id' => $cart_item['id'],
            'restaurant_id' => $cart_item['restaurant_id'],
            'name' => $cart_item['name'],
            'description' => $cart_item['description'],
            'price' => $cart_item['price'],
            'qty' => $cart_item['qty'],
            'available' => $cart_item['available'],
            'cart_id' => $cart_id,
            'cart_cookie' => $cookie_id,
        ]);
    }
    $cart_modifier_items = $cart_items['cart_modifier_items'];

    foreach($cart_modifier_items as $cart_modifier_item) {

        CartModifierItem::create([
            'item_id' => $cart_modifier_item['id'],
            'cart_item_id' => $cart_modifier_item['menu_item_id'],
            'name' => $cart_modifier_item['name'],
            'price' => $cart_modifier_item['price'],
            'cart_id' => $cart_id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your fields are in the fillable array in the respective models.

```
// let save the item Record
// am seeing an id in the object so lets update if id exist or 
// create if it does not

 $id = isset($request->input('item.id')) ? $request->input('item.id') : null;
 $cart = Cart::updateOrCreate(['id'=>$id],$request->input('item'))

// now let save or update cart_items
foreach($request->input('item.cart_items') as $cart_item){
   $cart_item_id = isset($cart_item['id']) ? $cart_item['id'] : null;
   $cartItem = $cart->cart_items()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$cart_item_id],$cart_item);

   // now let save for cart_modifier_items
   foreach($cart_item['cart_modifier_items'] as $cart_modifier_item){
      $cart_modifier_item_id = isset($cart_modifier_item['id']) ? $cart_modifier_item['id'] : null;
      $cartModifierItem = $cartItem->cart_modifier_items()->updateOrCreate(['id'=>$cart_modifier_item_id],$cart_modifier_item);
   }

}
```

You have an idea of how to loop through your record and update or create the record. The only issue you may encounter next is how to deal with saved data which has been deleted/removed from the frontend. Its up to you to deal with that. Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Please check my updated question

Comment: sorry i didnt see your code. just saw it. The key for your object is Cart so why are you doing $request->input('item'). i guess it should be $request->input('Cart') if i get it right.

Comment: It's called `item` because I send it as `item` from `angularJS`